# How do I pass reference to Activity for ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android, mortar

I am trying to use Square's Mortar and Flow

The problem is: `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from support-v7 requires to have a reference to the Activity

However `view.getContext()` returns `PathContext` so i get

`ClassCastException: flow.path.PathContext cannot be cast  to android.app.Activity`

So how do I get reference to activity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Context in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

Comment: @JaredBurrows No, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `getBaseContext()` method of `ContextWrapper` class that is superclass of `PathContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Спасибо! I've managed to find my activity like this: ((PathContext) ctx).getBaseContext().getBaseContext().getBaseContext().getBaseContext() But It does not look like good solution ;(

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly My answer has the official Google docs. Read the docs. If you are using an `Activity` all you need is `this`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I do not use activity or fragment. I've updated my question to mention it.

Comment: @KorniltsevAnatoly You down vote me then update your question. That's really counter intuitive.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, my fault.